# How to get an Object from an @ManyToOne association in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two entities: Galaxy

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "galaxies")
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class Galaxy {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "galaxy_id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "galaxy")
    private List<Planet> planet;

}
```

And Planet

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "planets")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Planet {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "galaxy_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Galaxy galaxy;

}
```

In this case, a Galaxy can have multiple planets, but a planet can be in one galaxy. I can see the galaxies and its planets
[image: Galaxies and its planets]

But I'm unable to see to which galaxy a following planet belongs
[image: Planets]

Is it possible to show in the postman the Galaxy entity that is in the Planet entity?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the `Controller` code and how you are mapping entity to response object?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what code you are using in second api. But seems you are returning planet entity instead of returning galaxy entity.

Comment: I have two entities, one is Planet and the second one is Galaxy, what I'd like to do is know the Galaxy name an x planet belongs. FOr instance, in the image I posted I have a Galaxy which name is Sunflower and I have a Planet inside it which name is Jupiter-534. If I call my galaxy repo I can see which planets belongs to that Galaxy. Now, I want to list a planet and know to which Galaxy belongs, for example, If I call Planet repo, I want to retrieve the planetId, name and the galaxyName. In the image, I retrieve only PlanetId and name but no the GalaxyName. is it due to relation in my tables?